# debugger in ipython is not working

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

I trying to use the debugger in ipython 3.1 on my python 2.7.9 installation on Windows 7.

Here is an example script:

```
def works_fine():
    a = 5
    b = 6
    assert(a + b == 11)

def throws_an_exception():
    a = 5
    b = 6
    assert(a + b == 10)

def calling_things():
    works_fine()
    throws_an_exception()

calling_things()
```

I step into the code with `%debug`.

I go up with `u`

Then I add a breakpoint at line 12 with `b 12`

I press `c`

Then instead of the debugger runs continue it prints out "ipdb> c" instead of continue.. How should I solve this?

```
> <ipython-input-7-c95b844c9880>(9)throws_an_exception()
      8     b = 6
----> 9     assert(a + b == 10)
     10 

ipdb> u
> <ipython-input-7-c95b844c9880>(13)calling_things() 2    12     works_fine()
---> 13     throws_an_exception()
     14 

ipdb> b 12 Breakpoint 3 at <ipython-input-7-c95b844c9880>:12
ipdb> c
```

Comment: How do you load the code into ipython?

Comment: I load it like this: on the first line inside the notebook: `def works_fine():
    a = 5
    b = 6
    assert(a + b == 11)

def throws_an_exception():
    a = 5
    b = 6
    assert(a + b == 10)

def calling_things():
    works_fine()
    throws_an_exception()

calling_things()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to put  the code in a file and run -d xxxx.py. After this the `c`ontinue works fine!

```
run -d ch03/ipython_bug.py
```

Comment: After an exception, `%debug` puts you in a *post-mortem* debugger - this lets you walk up and down the stack to investigate what was going on when the exception hit, but you can't continue or step through the code, because the exception has already stopped execution.